# Go Concurrent Write to csv: "slice bounds out of range"

Tags: csv, go

I'm trying to extract the certificates informations from a list of websites and write it to a csv.
I keep getting into the same error but not always at the same time and on different domains.

I get the error at line 63: `err := writer.Write(data)`

```
main.analyzeDomains(0xc0000840c0, 0xc0000126c0)
        /root/BreakCert/SSLCert/src/main.go:95 +0x5f
created by main.main
        /root/BreakCert/SSLCert/src/main.go:113 +0x1bf
panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range

goroutine 35 [running]:
bufio.(*Writer).Flush(0xc000024140, 0x400002400, 0x0)
        /usr/local/go/src/bufio/bufio.go:590 +0x1c0
bufio.(*Writer).WriteByte(0xc000024140, 0xc0000aa92c, 0xc000452500, 0x4d1)
        /usr/local/go/src/bufio/bufio.go:645 +0x96
bufio.(*Writer).WriteRune(0xc000024140, 0xc00000002c, 0x4d1, 0x4d1, 0x0)
        /usr/local/go/src/bufio/bufio.go:657 +0x1aa
encoding/csv.(*Writer).Write(0xc0000126c0, 0xc00060a000, 0x5, 0x8, 0x2, 0x1a)
        /usr/local/go/src/encoding/csv/writer.go:47 +0x4b8
main.storeCertificate(0xc00018cb00, 0xc0000126c0, 0xc000396380, 0x12)
        /root/BreakCert/SSLCert/src/main.go:63 +0x3e9
main.analyzeDomain(0xc000396380, 0x12, 0xc0000126c0)
        /root/BreakCert/SSLCert/src/main.go:88 +0x19d
main.analyzeDomains(0xc0000840c0, 0xc0000126c0)
        /root/BreakCert/SSLCert/src/main.go:95 +0x5f
created by main.main
        /root/BreakCert/SSLCert/src/main.go:113 +0x1bf
exit status 2
```

My code is

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "crypto/rsa"
    "crypto/tls"
    "crypto/x509"
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type CsvWriter struct {
    mutex     *sync.Mutex
    csvWriter *csv.Writer
}

func NewCsvWriter(fileName string) (*CsvWriter, error) {
    csvFile, err := os.Create(fileName)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    w := csv.NewWriter(csvFile)
    return &CsvWriter{csvWriter: w, mutex: &sync.Mutex{}}, nil
}

func (w *CsvWriter) Write(row []string) {
    w.mutex.Lock()
    w.csvWriter.Write(row)
    w.mutex.Unlock()
}

func (w *CsvWriter) Flush() {
    w.mutex.Lock()
    w.csvWriter.Flush()
    w.mutex.Unlock()
}

func storeCertificate(cert *x509.Certificate, writer *csv.Writer, domain string) {

    if v := cert.PublicKeyAlgorithm.String(); v == "RSA" {
        if len(cert.Issuer.Organization) != 0 {

            var data []string
            // Get Issuer Organization
            data = append(data, domain[:len(domain)-4])
            data = append(data, cert.Issuer.Organization[0])
            rsaPublicKey := cert.PublicKey.(*rsa.PublicKey)
            if rsaPublicKey != nil {
                data = append(data, rsaPublicKey.N.String())
                data = append(data, strconv.Itoa(rsaPublicKey.E))
                data = append(data, strconv.Itoa(rsaPublicKey.Size()))
                fmt.Println("Done: ", domain)
                if 6 <= len(data) {
                    data = data[:5]
                }
                err := writer.Write(data)
                if err != nil {
                    log.Fatal(err)
                }

            }

        }
    }

}

func analyzeDomain(domain string, writer *csv.Writer) {
    //fmt.Println("analyzing", domain)
    dialer := net.Dialer{}
    dialer.Timeout = 10 * time.Second
    conn, err := tls.DialWithDialer(&dialer, "tcp", domain, &tls.Config{
        InsecureSkipVerify: true,
    })
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("\x1b[31;1mfailed to connect to %s", domain), err, "\x1b[0m")
        return
    }
    defer conn.Close()
    for _, cert := range conn.ConnectionState().PeerCertificates {
        storeCertificate(cert, writer, domain)
    }
}

func analyzeDomains(queue chan string, writer *csv.Writer) {
    for {
        domain := <-queue
        analyzeDomain(domain, writer)

    }
}

func main() {
    // Creates a channel
    cs := make(chan string)

    // Creates result.csv
    file, err := os.Create("result.csv")

    //Verifies that the file has been created
    checkError("Cannot create file", err)
    defer file.Close()
    writer := csv.NewWriter(file)

    for i := 0; i < 80; i++ {
        go analyzeDomains(cs, writer)

    }
    writer.Flush()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        line := scanner.Text()
        if !strings.Contains(line, ":") {
            line = line + ":443"
        }
        cs <- line
    }
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
}

func checkError(message string, err error) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(message, err)
    }
}
```

and is used like that

```
cat domains | go run main.go
```

domains contains one url per line.

Comment: you have multiple instances of `analyzeDomains` that runs simultaneously against the same `writer` instance without any synchronization mechanism to prevent concurrent access.

Comment: you can only have one consumer of the writer instance. You are allowed to have multiple instances of dialer simultaneously.

Comment: You wrote a thread-safe writer, but you're still using the underlying csv writer which is not safe for concurrent access. Also, you should wait for analyzeDomains goroutines to complete using a WaitGroup.

Comment: And range over `queue` in `analyzeDomains` so that you can `close` it in `main` once you've fed all the lines in.

Comment: you should be using a  `chan []string` as output to `storeCertificate` and have one extra routine, reading from the new chan, and writing to the csv writer instance. As mentioned, you should use an instance of sync.WaitGroup to synchronize.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I get it now. Really new to go. The issue for @Adrian answer is that my input file is huge. Millions of urls, therefore I need to not store too much values in the ram

Comment: My comment would have no impact on how much memory is used. It would just improve the concurrency handling and make it possible to use a `WaitGroup` as @BurakSerdar suggested (which you should).

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll try that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is one solution to OP problem

```
// echo -e "google.com\ncnn.com\nstackoverflow.com" | go run main.go
package main

import (
  "bufio"
  "crypto/rsa"
  "crypto/tls"
  "crypto/x509"
  "encoding/csv"
  "io"
  "log"
  "net"
  "os"
  "strconv"
  "strings"
  "sync"
  "time"
)

func certToCSV(cert *x509.Certificate, domain string) []string {
  var data []string
  data = append(data, domain[:len(domain)-4])
  var org string
  if len(cert.Issuer.Organization) > 0 {
    org = cert.Issuer.Organization[0]
  }
  data = append(data, org)
  if cert.PublicKey != nil {
    rsaPublicKey := cert.PublicKey.(*rsa.PublicKey)
    data = append(data, rsaPublicKey.N.String())
    data = append(data, strconv.Itoa(rsaPublicKey.E))
    data = append(data, strconv.Itoa(rsaPublicKey.Size()))
  }
  return data
}

func getCerts(d string) ([]*x509.Certificate, error) {
  out := []*x509.Certificate{}
  dialer := net.Dialer{}
  dialer.Timeout = 10 * time.Second
  conn, err := tls.DialWithDialer(&dialer, "tcp", d, &tls.Config{
    InsecureSkipVerify: true,
  })
  if err != nil {
    return out, err
  }
  defer conn.Close()
  for _, cert := range conn.ConnectionState().PeerCertificates {
    if v := cert.PublicKeyAlgorithm.String(); v != "RSA" {
      log.Printf("%q not using RSA algorithm but %q", d, cert.PublicKeyAlgorithm)
      continue
    }
    if len(cert.Issuer.Organization) < 1 {
      log.Printf("%q does not have organization", d)
      continue
    }
    out = append(out, cert)
  }
  return out, err
}

func analyze(dst chan []string, src chan string, errs chan error) {
  for domain := range src {
    certs, err := getCerts(domain)
    if err != nil {
      errs <- err
      continue
    }
    for _, cert := range certs {
      record := certToCSV(cert, domain)
      dst <- record
    }
  }
}

func readCSVFile(dst chan string, fp string) error {
  file, err := os.Create(fp)
  if err != nil {
    return err
  }
  defer file.Close()

  scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
  for scanner.Scan() {
    line := scanner.Text()
    if !strings.Contains(line, ":") {
      line = line + ":443"
    }
    dst <- line
  }
  return scanner.Err()
}

func readCSV(dst chan string, src io.Reader) error {
  scanner := bufio.NewScanner(src)
  for scanner.Scan() {
    line := scanner.Text()
    if !strings.Contains(line, ":") {
      line = line + ":443"
    }
    dst <- line
  }
  return scanner.Err()
}

func writeCSV(dst io.Writer, src chan []string, errs chan error) {
  w := csv.NewWriter(dst)
  for record := range src {
    if err := w.Write(record); err != nil {
      errs <- err
    }
    w.Flush()
  }
  if err := w.Error(); err != nil {
    errs <- err
  }
}

func main() {
  var wg sync.WaitGroup
  errs := make(chan error)
  src := make(chan string)
  t1 := make(chan []string)

  // synchronize all routines to close errs once
  go func() {
    wg.Wait()
    close(errs)
  }()

  var wg2 sync.WaitGroup
  // analyze multiple domains in //
  for i := 0; i < 4; i++ {
    wg.Add(1)
    wg2.Add(1)
    go func() {
      defer wg.Done()
      defer wg2.Done()
      analyze(t1, src, errs)
    }()
  }

  // synchronize with analyze routines to close t1
  go func() {
    wg2.Wait()
    close(t1)
  }()

  // write the csv file
  wg.Add(1)
  go func() {
    defer wg.Done()
    writeCSV(os.Stdout, t1, errs)
  }()

  // read the csv, fail if an error occurs reading the source
  wg.Add(1)
  go func() {
      defer wg.Done()
      err := readCSV(src, os.Stdin)
      if err != nil {
          log.Fatal(err)
      }
      close(src)
  }()

  // read and print errors, adjust exit code
  var exitCode int
  for err := range errs {
    log.Println(err)
    exitCode = 1
  }
  os.Exit(exitCode)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking into it and found an issue. After a certain time it stops. Around 200 or so certificates. I'll try to find the issue and post the correction.

Comment: unclear. might be network related. you are not setting any timeout anywhere.

Comment: In the dialer settings there is `dialer.Timeout = 10 * time.Second`. Could it be an issue with the routines ?

Comment: I located an issue in the code and updated the answer. It was blocking because the error channel was not drained, thus as soon as all 4 analyze routines met an error, the program would block. To detect and solve those problems you can use the http profiler to check status of all routines within the program at runtime.

Comment: Thanks ! It's working. Also thanks for http profiler. It is awesome !